# clojure: add index to vector of maps

Tags: vector, clojure

I have a vector of maps. I want to associate an index element for each element.

Example:

```
(append-index [{:name "foo"} {:name "bar"} {:name "baz"}])
```

should return

```
[{:name "foo" :index 1} {:name "bar" :index 2} {:name "baz" :index 3}]
```

What is the best way to implement append-index function?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I just want the position in the vector as index. I think I actually found a function that will do what I want so I'll just answer this myself and close this.

Comment: Side note: if you think about it, it doesn't make much sense to add the index on the map. You can add it when you fetch it. Be lazy my friend.

Comment: This is part of a larger thing that involves fetching recursive structure from database via external library and then sorting it (at html/javascript side).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, Clojure starts counting vector elements from 0, so you probably want to get

```
[{:index 0, :name "foo"} {:index 1, :name "bar"} {:index 2, :name "baz"}]
```

You could do it pretty easily with [`map-indexed` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed)

```
(defn append-index [coll]
  (map-indexed #(assoc %2 :index %1) coll))
```

Answer (score 1):

just adding some fun:

```
(defn append-index [items]
  (map assoc items (repeat :index) (range)))
```